# Find dependency chain between two classes on Intellij IDEA diagram

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, uml, diagram

I'm trying to find an automatic way of getting from here:

[image: Initial status]

To here:

[image: Final status]

Without having to manually add classes B and C. I've tried using the find dependencies action when right clicking on class A, but it only shows direct dependencies and if class A has lots of dependencies it's hard to know what "branch" to follow to find class D.

Comment: This is not a "dependency flow" (what should that be?) but a composition.

Comment: I meant the fact that A uses B that uses C that uses D. I used "flow" as I didn't know what word to use :(

Comment: I'd call it composition chain (not a tech term per se). Can't help with the tool itself.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a way to do this, at least in terms of displaying the connections between the classes in the hierarchy.

First, I opened the two classes alongside each other using the "move right" on one of the editor tabs (see [Splitting and Unsplitting Editor tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html).

Second, I selected both class names by holding Alt + Shift and dragging my mouse across each class name (which triggers the [multiple cursors feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/multicursor.html).

Third, I hit the keyboard shortcut to [view the class hierarchy as a UML diagram](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/viewing-class-hierarchy-as-a-class-diagram.html) (⌥⇧⌘U on my Mac).

You can then hit the "Show Dependencies" button in the UML editor to get the full dependency view around your two target classes.

This was in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.